# How to handle QDate click event if date is already selected

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I’m using “QDate” Quasar component.
I need to handle event when user clicks on the date. QDate provides an event named "@input " but this event is only triggered when model changes. But what if user clicks on already selected date. How to capture the event in that case?

Can anyone help me on this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

in quasar v1 example

```
@input="() => $refs.qDateProxy.hide()"
```

in quasar v2 vue 3 maybe use

```
@update:model-value -> function(value, reason, details)
```

Documentation
https://quasar.dev/vue-components/date#basic
QDate API - click on events

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found any problem with the event mentioned! in case still have the problem let's know your quasar version and vuejs too.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  data: {
    message: 'كيف حالك اليوم؟',
    date: '2019/02/01',
  }
});
```

```html
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@1.15.23/dist/quasar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@^2.0.0/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@1.15.23/dist/quasar.umd.min.js"></script>

<div id="root">
  <h5>{{ message }}</h5>
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="">
      <q-date v-model="date" @input="$q.notify('date clicked')" />


    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Tested configuration: quasar@1.15.23